# Finite generatedness of homotopy groups of a Lie group

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, lie-groups, homotopy-theory

Let $G$ be a (connected, WLOG compact) lie group. I have seen it stated (without proof) that all of it's homotopy groups are finitely generated. I have no clue how to prove this even for $\pi_1$. Once this is settled the general case can probably be done by assuming that $G$ is simply connected and compact (by passing to the universal cover and then to a maximal compact subgroup) and arguing more generally that every compact simply connected (smooth) manifold has finitely generated homotopy groups, though I do not know how to prove such a statement. I have a feeling that one can use the fact that the homologies are f.g and some sort of Hurewicz (and maybe some spectral sequence argument) to show this, but I don't really understand how. So my questions are basically:

1. How does one prove that a Lie group has finitely generated fundamental group? and:
2. How to show that a simply connected compact (smooth) manifold has finitely generated homotopy groups?

Any reference/explicit argument will be appreciated.
$$$$
[edit] Of course the fundamental group of $G$, being abelian, must be isomorphic to the first homology which is finitely generated. Hence my first question is completely stupid. what about the second?

Comment: Regarding 2: page 2 of [this paper](https://www.emis.de/journals/GM/vol13nr1/damian/damian.pdf) cites 'Groupes d'homotopie et classes de groupes abéliens' by Serre. The discussion [here](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Are_the_homotpy_groups_of_a_compact_manifold_finitely_generated) also mentions Serre but sketches portions of the argument.

Comment: A classic argument due to Serre involving spectral sequences shows that if $X$ is simply connected, then its homotopy groups are f.g. iff its homology groups are f.g. For details see e.g.: http://www.math.uni-frankfurt.de/~johannso/SkriptAll/SkriptTopAlg/SkriptTopCW/homotop12.pdf

Comment: If you ask about the second homotopy group of a Lie group, then not only it is finitely generated: it is in fact trivial! See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8957/homotopy-groups-of-lie-groups for references and a sketch of a proof.